# Android Client connecting to the Server over SSL

Tags: java, android, ssl, sun

I am trying to create an SSL connection from android client to the server over SSL.
In the very beginning I was always getting

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common on the server

when connection was attempted.

After some investigation I realized that Android uses Bouncy Castle SSL implementation and the cipher suites there are different from those SUN provides. So I've added Bouncy Castle provider to the server. The original problem went away, but I now get

Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: NO SERVER CERTIFICATE FOUND

I am not sure why I get this. I have generated the certificate. Granted I am using JKS to store it, but why would it matter? It's just a format of storage, the certificate should be exactly the same.

If anyone has done non HTTP client server programming on Android using SSL I would really appreciate any pointers on what I need to do.

Comment: Adding the BouncyCastle provider to the server shouldn't change anything. At the end of the day, the cipher suites identifiers that are exchanged have nothing to do with the names used for their configuration. It sounds like your server certificate might not be configured properly.

Comment: The cipher suites supported can't be all that different. RFC 2246 mandates a large set of required cipher suites that all implementations must support.

Answer (score 0):

When I got this, the reason was that the server didn't have proper server certificate loaded. So double-check your server indeed has certificate to offer.